# Sorting A List In A MultiSelect Dropdown

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to sort the list of a specific class alphabetically in the multiselect DD. I tried using the .sort() function but it doesn't work. Throws and error.

```
 ProfileField(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: CustomTheme.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.58),
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 1.25,
                  color: CustomTheme.lightGreen,
                ),
              ),
              child: MultiSelectDialogField(
                buttonText: Text('Select Specialities'),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                ),
                buttonIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_drop_down_rounded,
                  color: CustomTheme.deepShadedBlue,
                  size: 24,
                ),
                initialValue: state.profile?.speciality
                        ?.map((e) => e as String)
                        .toList() ??
                    [],
                items: state.specialityList
                        ?.map((e) => MultiSelectItem(e.id, e.content as String))
                        .toList() ??
                    [],
                listType: MultiSelectListType.CHIP,
                onConfirm: (values) {
                  List<String> specialities =
                      values.map((e) => e as String).toList();
                  cubit.updateUser(state.copyWith(
                      profile:
                          state.profile?.copyWith(speciality: specialities)));
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

I want the list state.specialityList to sort alphabetically

Comment: I don't see any .sort() being used, why don't you sort the list before pushing it in the state?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to suggest anything, because you didn't provide any info about contents of this list. However, sort() methods works only if list elements implement Comparable interface, which is used inside sort function. Assuming that list contains some custom data class, you can instead use sortedBy() method. You can pass it a lambda, that should return something that can be compared, e.g. String or a Number.
For instance, if your Speciality class has a "name" property, which is string, calling:

```
specialityList.sortedBy{ it.name }
```

should do the trick.

If my assumption is not correct, I suggest you provide more info about contents of your list.